# Would Julia have wanted to meet with O'Brien if not for Winston?

Tags: george-orwell, nineteen-eighty-four

In George Orwell's *1984* I am trying to prove that Winston influenced Julia to be more proactive in rebelling against the Party. So I am wondering if Julia's views on actively trying to take down the Party changed after being with Winston? In my essay I am trying to prove she would never have met with O'Brien or been actively searching for ways to destroy the Party if not for Winston's influence.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. She generally seemed very uninterested in anything political. She was not interested in reading "The Book" and didn't even understand why Winston was so excited about that photo which was proof of the Party lying.

I believe she was more of a passive rebel. She had a sort of instinct to rebel against the social norms of the party but never actually planned to destroy the party.

I believe that O'Brien would never have asked her to meet with him alone. It is very probable that he knew about her way before he knew about Winston since she had been having sexual affairs way before Winston even bought his book. So O'Brien probably knew about her but chose not to ask Her.

I hope my thoughs will help you with your essay.